# Changes in magento2 javascript files does not apply on my storefront

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2

I want to make changes in some magento-2 javascript files, but the result does not change on the storefront.

For example I change the text "Are you sure you want to remove this item from your Compare Products list?" in file \vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\js\view\compare-products.js.

Then I delete all files in the folders:
/pub/static/ and /var/view_preprocessed/

Run the commands:
service varnish restart and 
magento setup: static-content: deploy

But there is no result!

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can solve your problem from here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2

Comment: I do not create a new module, I try to change the core files

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome:

1. Push F12
2. Network Tab - Click to Disable cache